# CSS Star rating - select all stars before the hovered one

Tags: css

I want to create a similar to IMDB rating system that when you hover 9/10 for example, all 9 stars are filled instead of just the one hovered. I tried something like this:

```
.add-rate:hover,
.add-rate:hover ~ .add-rate:before {
```

But I am really not sure what the `~` symbol is and how it is suppose to work.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hn29xs97/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` is a [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors). To get this to work, you want to reverse the order of the stars (you can use `flex` with `flex-direction` to do that visually) and target `.add-rate:hover ~ .add-rate`

```css
.add-rate {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: gray;
}

.add-rate:hover,
.add-rate:hover ~ .add-rate {
  color: orange;
}

.stars {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-box">Rating: 1/10<br>
  <div class="stars">
    <span class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '1', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '2', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span
    class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '3', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '4', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '5', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>      <span class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '6', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '7', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span
      class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '8', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '9', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span class="add-rate" onmouseup="rate('montauk', '10', 'rate.php')"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: @user3628807 awesome, you bet :)